# How to modify/customize the tooltip of video player from Plyr?

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

I am using the library of a html5 video player from https://github.com/sampotts/plyr and trying to integrate it to my React app. The default tooltip when the mouse hovers over the seek bar (progress bar) is the time at the format MM:SS (ex. `03:15`).

What I want to accomplish is the add more details to it for example `03:15 - Section 1`, `05:50 - Section 2` where the added details will come from state.

The closest I can see from the documentation is the tooltips attribute where you can only change it being visible or not when creating a new instance of the player.